# Is there a way to automate sideloading without the recovery menu OR automate navigating the recovery menu in Android?

Tags: recovery-mode, automation, side-loading

This is for some automation I want to setup. I want to be able to sideload in an automated fashion for some testing, without any human intervention. The normal way to do an OTA is `adb reboot recovery` then navigate the recovery menu, then select sideload over ADB, then `adb sideload <ota-file>/zip`. The problem is the manual navigation of the recovery menu part. I want to sideload without having to manually do that part, either by automation navigation of the recovery menu, or by skipping the recovery menu part completely. Is it possible to `adb shell input keyevent` on the recovery menu, or something similar? Is there a different sideload command that can be run on a device from the root of the recovery menu or from the fastboot menu or from the OS itself?

Comment: Have a look at [Pixel Flasher](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/pixelflasher-a-gui-tool-for-flashing-updating-rooting-managing-pixel-phones.4415453/&ved=2ahUKEwjsgdObyuL_AhW-9zgGHbnvC_cQFnoECA4QAQ&usg=AOvVaw0P-FUMhWAod1jNBwcs7QBH)